# Defining a parameter of a struct variable in a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, parameters, constructor

I am using a struct variable inside a class and I would like to assign the value of a parameter of that variable in the class constructor.

But I can not find a way to compile. could you show me how to do it? This is an example of my code

```
struct mystruct
{
   int myvar;
}

class myclass
{
   mystruct s_;

public:
   myclass(int n) : s_.myvar{ n } {}
};
```

Comment: `myclass(int n) {s_.myvar = n;}`

Comment: myclass(int n) : s_{n} {}

Comment: or since C++20, a more clear aggregate init version using designators : `myclass(int n) : s_{ .myvar = n } {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mystruct` would need a suitable constructor which takes an `int`ger as an argument, for that.

```
struct mystruct
{
   int myvar;
   mystruct(int val)  // provide this constructor and good to go!
      : myvar{ val }
   {}
};
```

Or **[Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)**

Since `mystruct` is an aggregate type you could do the *[aggregate initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)* too. This would be the minimal change required for your case and do not require the constructor in `mystruct`.

```
class myclass
{
   mystruct s_;
public:
   myclass(int n)
      : s_{ n } // aggregate initialization
   {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize s_.myvar inside the constructor like so:

```
Myclass(int n) {
    s_.myvar = n;
}
```